# Есть ли способ сделать window.opener.reload с нужным параметром на JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Основное окно открывает дочернее, то в свою очередь при сохранении данных перезагружает родительское окно с параметром которое получает в дочернем. Как-то так?!